# Adding values from previous row into current row

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sum, sql-server-2014

I have a simple table and I want add a value from previous row into current and value of current in next row so it keeps on going until the end.

Please have a look at the following table data.

```
ID  Value ValueIncrement 
1     2          0
2     3          5  (2+3)
3     9          14 (2+3+9)
4     6          20 (2+3+9+6)
5     3          23 (2+3+9+6+3) 
6     1          24 (2+3+9+6+3+1)  
7     2          26 (2+3+9+6+3+1+2)
8     0          26 (2+3+9+6+3+1+2+0)
9     2          30 (2+3+9+6+3+1+2+0+2)
```

I am looking for a select query which can enable me to add values continuously.

Comment: Why ValueIncrement starts with 0, it should be 2?

Answer (score 2):

You can do a window sum:

```
select id, value, sum(value) over (order by id) valueincrement
from mytable
order by id
```

**[Demo on SQL Server 2014 Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=4dc338427bdf1d6d2d542d8f36af5165)**:

```
id | value | valueincrement
-: | ----: | -------------:
 1 |     2 |              2
 2 |     3 |              5
 3 |     9 |             14
 4 |     6 |             20
 5 |     3 |             23
 6 |     1 |             24
 7 |     2 |             26
 8 |     0 |             26
 9 |     2 |             28
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a `correlated sub-query` if you are working with a small table (otherwise,**for performance reason, you should absolutely not use this approach if you can use window-functions**). I am assuming your valueincrement column starting with a 0 is a typo and not by design. Let us know if otherwise.

```
select *, (select sum(value) from mytable t2 where t1.id >= t2.id) as valueincrement
from mytable t1
order by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a recursive sum

```
INSERT INTO #tmpPrueba
VALUES(2),(3),(9),(6),(3),(1),(2),(0),(2)

CREATE TABLE #tmpTest
(nId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
nValor INT NOT NULL)

SELECT *
FROM #tmpTest;

SELECT SUM(nValor) OVER (ORDER BY nId ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM #tmpTest;
```

Comment: Thanks for giving it thought guys, GMB answers suit's the current need really well.